# Proof, number theory

Tags: number-theory

Prove, that we can find for any **a** natural number infinite number of b, without the digit 0 natural number, so that the sum of the digits in b and in ab are the same.

For example:

12*99=1188

12*999=11988

12*9999=119988

12*99999=1199988

The number of digits in 99 is 18, also in 1188
The number of digits in 999 is 27, also in 11988
....
So I think I should find out some general notation system for this, and I should use the induction method. But I dont know exactly how should I prove this rigorously. It is like magic to me.

Comment: It is not magic. Just show that $12\cdot 999\cdots 999=11999\cdots 99988$. Of course the sum of digits is equal, because we have only two different pairs $1,1,8,8$ and $9,9,9,9$, where  $1+8=9$.

Comment: You simply have $$12\cdot (10^n-1)=12\cdot 10^n-12$$ hence we subtract $12$ from $120\cdots 0$ with $n$ zeros , if $n$ is the number of nines in the second factor , the result is clear.